# Tokenizing Japanese text in R: Only first line of the specified column is tokenized

Tags: r, dataframe, tokenize, tidytext, mecab

I am trying to tokenize a collection of tweets with the Japanese tokenizer `RMeCab`, specifically the function `RMeCabDF` (for dataframes).

The documentation states the following usage:

> **RMeCabDF**
>
> **Description**
>
> RMeCabDF takes data frames as the first argument, and analyzes the
>   columns specified by the second argument. Blank data should be
>   replaced with NA. If 1 is designated as the third argument, it returns
>   each morpheme in its basic form.
>
> **Usage**
>
> RMeCabDF(dataf, coln, mypref, dic = "", mecabrc = "", etc = "")
>
> **Arguments**
>
> *dataf*    data.frame
>
> *coln*     Column number or name which include Japanese sentences
>
> *mypref*   Default being 0, the same morphemic forms that appear on the text are returned. If 1 is designated, the basic forms of them are instead.
>
> *dic*  to specify user dictionary, e.x. ishida.dic
>
> *mecabrc*  not implemented (to specify mecab resource file)
>
> *etc*  other options to mecab

So following this, I use the following code to tokenize the column number `89` in the dataframe `trump_ja`:

```
trump_ja_tokens <- RMeCabDF(trump_ja, coln = 89)
```

This results in a `List of 1` - but as you can see, the dataframe has 989 rows.

[image]

Where did my other rows go?

Do I have to tokenize row by row? If so, is there any way to automate this process to avoid typing 1000 lines of code (or using Excel to produce 1000 lines of code)?

Comment: I have no idea about RMecab, but maybe [this tutorial](https://tutorials.quanteda.io/language-specific/japanese/) from `quanteda` might help you further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `RMeCab` tokenizer with tidytext, in the way that [this user](https://github.com/juliasilge/tidytext/issues/10) did. You would set it up like so:

```
df %>%
    unnest_tokens(word, text, token = RMeCab::RMeCabC)
```

where `df` is your data frame, `word` is the new column you are going to create, and `text` is the old column that you already have that contains the text you want to tokenize. The `token` argument in `unnest_tokens()` can take a function as an argument, for cases just like these.